# Synchronized and Code reorder in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, synchronized, java-memory-model

In some link it is given that code reorder inside synchronized block is possible, whereas some other site is telling not possible. Can u please give an example to describe what actually happens in respect of code reordering when synchronized is used?

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible reorderings:

- statements before or after the synchronized block may be moved inside the synchronized block (provided they are not in a different synchronized block of course) - it is sometimes called [the "roach motel" principle](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2008-April/005090.html)
- statements inside a synchronized block may be reordered as long as the modification is sequentially consistent (i.e. the effect is not visible from other code that shares a happens-before relationship with the block)

But more importantly: **if your code is properly synchronized, these reorderings won't affect the execution of your program**, which is all you should care about.

Example (all variables originally at 0):

Thread1:

```
a=1;
synchronized(lock) {
    b=1;
    c=1;
}
d=1;
```

Thread2:

```
synchronized(lock) {
    if (a==1) print(b); // can print 0 or 1
    if (b==1) print(a)/print(c); // always prints 1
    if (b==1) print(d); // can print 0 or 1
    if (d==1) print(a)/print(b)/print(c); // always prints 1
}
```

In particular, moving `d=1` to before `c=1` or moving `a=1` to after `b=1` is allowed as it is not something that Thread 2 would be able to observe, because the synchronized block executed by Thread 1 looks like an atomic operation from Thread 2.

On the other hand, a thread that does not use the same lock would be able to observe these reorderings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But suppose I have a code after synchronized block. As per the first norm, that code can be taken inside synchronized block. Again as per the second norm code inside the synchronized block can be reordered untill happens before relationship is not violated. So isnt it the case that compliler sometime can reorder the while block of code inside synchronization along with the code that appears after the block and taken inside the synchronized block?

Comment: Not sure I understand what while block you are talking about - but yes in theory the compiler could reorder code after the synchronized block to before some of the statements within the synchronized block (but not before the block).

Answer (score 4):

The runtime may reorder operations as long as happens-before is respected. The spec [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.

and

> More specifically, if two actions share a happens-before relationship, they do not necessarily have to appear to have happened in that order to any code with which they do not share a happens-before relationship. Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads in another thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to those reads.

In particular, if one thread does:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    x = 1;
    y = 1;
}
```

and another does:

```
if (y == 1) System.out.println(x);
```

there is no happens-before relationship between these threads, and the other thread may observe `y` to have been assigned before `x` was, and print 0.